# Why is my AndroidHttpClient not sending params when I call Execute?

Tags: java, android, http

I've got an `AsyncTask` set up to create an `AndroidHttpClient` and call `Execute`, with a `HttpPost` and `BasicHttpContext` objects I provide.  I set up the `HttpPost` like so:

```
HttpPost myPost = new HttpPost("http://192.168.1.66:8080/login.html");
BasicHttpParams httpParams = new BasicHttpParams();
httpParams.setParameter("cmd", "Login");
httpParams.setParameter("Username", "test");
httpParams.setParameter("Password", "password");
myPost.setParams(httpParams);
```

When I execute the command, it retrieves the login page instead of the results of logging in. After monitoring the process on the server side, it seems that this is because the HTTP request arrived with no params attached!  So what am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
            HttpPost post = new HttpPost("http://192.168.1.66:8080/login.html");
            List<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>(
                    3);
            nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("cmd", "Login"
                    .getText().toString()));
            nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("Username", "test"
                    .getText().toString()));

            nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("Password", "Password"
                    .getText().toString()));

            post.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));
```

Answer (score 1):

```
List<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs=...;
HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost(url);
httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));
```

Try this.

[HttpPost docs](http://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client-ga/httpclient/apidocs/org/apache/http/client/methods/HttpPost.html)

> The HTTP POST method is defined in section 9.5 of RFC2616:
>
> The POST method is used to request that the origin server accept the
>   **entity enclosed** in the request as a new subordinate of the resource
>   identified by the Request-URI in the Request-Line...

The reason why this class has setParams() is because it implements [HttpMessage](http://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-core-ga/httpcore/apidocs/org/apache/http/HttpMessage.html?is-external=true) that has it. It may/may not be used?(not sure, it might be there for other impelmentations?) but basically you use `setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));` to post it

Answer (score 0):

You need to actually set the `httpParams` object into the request using `setEntity`:

`myPost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(httpParams, HTTP.UTF_8));`

Comment: Hmm. So if `SetEntity` attaches the params object to the POST object, what does `SetParams` do?

Answer (score 0):

**[setParams()](https://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-core-ga/httpcore/apidocs/org/apache/http/HttpMessage.html#setParams(org.apache.http.params.HttpParams))** sets parameters governing the processing of the message.  These message parameters have nothing to do with the *Entity* transmitted **with** the message.

The simplest way I have found to construct a multipart entity is using the **[MultipartEntityBuilder](http://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client-ga/httpmime/apidocs/org/apache/http/entity/mime/MultipartEntityBuilder.html)** (from **org.apache.http.entity.mime**):

```
  mpe = MultipartEntityBuilder.create();
  mpe.addTextBody("Username", "test");
  mpe.addTextBody("Password", "password");
  mpe.addTextBody("cmd",      "Login");

  req.setEntity(mpe.build());
```

The answer previously accepted is unnecessarily complex and actually yields a **x-www-form-urlencoded** entity, not a multipart form as you intended.